# how to make LAN without router (linux)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, lan

So I have two laptops, one of them Dual-Booted with Ubuntu and Windows 10, the other Dual-Booted with Windows 10 and Linux mint(the one my friend has).
I have some games I would like to play over LAN at a friends house.
He has no internet, nor a router.
How would I go about making a LAN connection with only an Ethernet cord, or preferably, cordless (one of the computers emulating a wifi router,maybe?).
P.S. i would rather do this through linux

Comment: Do these games work on Linux in the first place?

Comment: yes,they do work on linux. an example im going to use is Minecraft

Comment: The easiest way is to get a cheap switch. You will need to manually set the addresses on the PCs.

Comment: sorry,not spending any money on hardware r now

Comment: would it be possible to perform the wireless ad-hoc in https://smallbusiness.chron.com/hook-up-two-pcs-router-37280.html in linux?
I.E. a WLAN for two laptops